# AMCharts 4 - Map stroke uneven when applied to single countries

Tags: maps, amcharts

[image]

As you can see in the above image. I've applied a stroke to the USA. However the top of the mainland stroke is clearly thinner than the rest of the stroke. My config is below:

```
  polygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color('#2c2626')
  polygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 0
  polygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true
```

And then I have an adaptor to stroke the active country,

```
polygonTemplate.adapter.add('strokeWidth', (stroke, target) => {
    if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.dataContext && this.selectedCountry) {
      if (target.dataItem.dataContext.id === this.selectedCountry.id) {
        return 2
      }
    }
    return stroke
  })
```

From what I can find from examples online, this is the right way to apply a stroke. Is there a way I can make this stroke even all around the country? It happens on most countries but there are a few where it's not as bad..

EDIT: Thanks to Sam for his help, I now have an even stroke. But it seems I've got to press on a new country twice for it to take the active state - once to toggle the old country to inactive, then once again to add the active state. GIF below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is, that the bordering countries are overlapping the stroke of your selected country. I increased the `strokeWidth` to 10 and set the `fillOpacity` to 0.6. You can clearly see that in the following picture or in [that](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzNJax?editors=0010) code pen.

[image: example image]

Also setting the `zIndex` in an adapter doesn't change anything for me.

But you can use [states](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/):

Create an active (or a custom) state with the properties you want to use. You can also use `zIndex` there. Now set that state to every country you want to highlight.

```
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
polygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.6;
polygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color('#2c2626');
polygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 0;
polygonTemplate.zIndex = 0;
polygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;

// Create active state
var activeState = polygonTemplate.states.create("active");
activeState.properties.strokeWidth = 10;
activeState.properties.zIndex = 1;

// Create an event to toggle "active" statestate
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  ev.target.isActive = !ev.target.isActive;
  console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.id);
});

chart.events.once('inited', event => {
  polygonSeries.mapPolygons.values.find(i => i.dataItem.dataContext.id === 'US').isActive = true;
});
```

Here is the result:

[image: example image]

[This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEWxgW) code pen shows the states example. Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

To use double click to toggle the active state you can just replace the `hit` event with the `doublehit` event ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygon/#doublehit_event)). But you maybe want to disable zoom on double click now. That's possible with the following lines ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/disabling-zoom-and-pan-on-a-map-chart/#Disabling_double_click_zoom)):

```
chart.seriesContainer.events.disableType("doublehit");
chart.chartContainer.background.events.disableType("doublehit");
```

I created [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzNmpJ) code pen to show you an example.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. It seems to be working, however i need to press countries twice for the active state to trigger. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can just replace the `hit` event with `doublehit`. I updated my answer according to that and included a code pen.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry Sam, perhaps I was not clear - I've edited my OP to include a gif of what is happening. But basically it seems like I've got to click once to toggle off the active state from one country, then click again to add it to the new country.

Comment: Nevermind! It was my only computed function in vue which was destroying the active prop AMcharts makes :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/dyXPRVR
You must set some zIndex to a big number for hovered polygon and also call toFront() in order to make it higher than the previously hovered polygon:

```
polygonTemplate.events.on("over", function(event){
    event.target.zIndex = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    event.target.toFront();
})
```